# Creating a Web App with Bootstrap and Tomcat Embedded and Java SE 8 not running

Tags: java, oracle, maven, tomcat, java-8

I am following this Oracle tutorial

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html

I have downloaded the zip containing the maven project and run it following the instructions here

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html

But when I execute the final command

```
java -jar employees-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get this error message:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.employees.Main

I have set the JAVA_HOME to point to the Oracle jdk1.8.0_102.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial, and then downloaded their example and tried again to make sure it wasn't me. I didn't get your Main class error, that worked fine, but Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 says 404 The requested resource is not available no matter what URL I use, /, /index.jsp, /employee. I had much better luck with Heroku's "Create a Java Web Application Using Embedded Tomcat" guide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Main class in [step 1](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_app_embedded_tomcat/basic_app-tomcat-embedded.html#section9)?

```
package com.example.employees;

import java.util.Optional;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Main {

    public static final Optional<String> port = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PORT"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String contextPath = "/";
        String appBase = ".";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();     
        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(port.orElse("8080") ));
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);
        tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, appBase);
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said I have downloaded the zip which contains the complete application. If you replicate in this way, just be careful, my compiler complained it founded non UTF-8 characters in the class comments in four of the classes (which is the copyright symbol). I have just deleted the character and that issue was gone

Comment: There were no other build warnings?  And you didn't edit any of the files (other than removing the copyright symbol)?  Did you try doing a `mvn clean compile; mvn package` again?

Comment: I did it again, same error message, no other warning from java. I am working on ubuntu 16_04, I have downloaded the zip, right click and Extract Here. Then the rest from the command line as explained in the tutorial

Comment: After specifing the project.build.sourceEncoding to cp1252, the encoding problem is resolved. Now it seems a problem with maven. Using maven 3.3.3 everything goes well, while with maven 3.3.9 the problem arises. The difference is in how maven is packaging the jar, which has a very different structure in the two cases. In the second one (3.3.9), the source package with the .class files is under WEB-INF/classes, while in the working case it's in the root directory

Comment: After investigating a while. I have found out that the actual problem is not with maven 3.3.9, but with the maven-assembly-plugin from version 2.2-beta-5, which work well, to version 2.2 (2.6 is the same) which works in the undesired way.

Comment: Finally I managed to solve it. It's just as simple as changing the packaging from war to jar. So the tutorial has few mistakes in the configuration. The fact that it was working fine with the beta versions of the plugin was because that version just ignore the packaging war tag.